# Does one have to hit a cushion during a break in snooker?

Tags: rules, snooker

I was wondering during the break in a snooker game can I simple strike the cue softly and just touch the reds. Or do I have to hit the cue ball and make sure it rebounds and hits a cushion?

I just wanted to tap the reds so it lands closer to the reds without breaking the triangle bunch as much..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in snooker, on any shot. You just have to hit the correct ball first. The break shot has no extra rules.

The official rules of snooker are [here, the World Professional Billiards and Snooker Association](https://www.wpbsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/official-rules-of-the-game.pdf)

No specific rule applies to the opening shot of a frame, nor is there anything requiring cushions to be hit.
There is a rule about cushions in the section for Shoot-out Snooker, but this variant is rarely played.

Pool does have rules in these areas, but that is a different sport.